# How to end a batch file with an open command window at a certain folder location

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

This seems like it should be ridiculously simple but I cannot find the answer online or in these forums.

I want to run a command from a batch file, leave the command window open and end at a particular file location.

I can't seem to get both to happen in the same window.  This is for a script to run an automated task everytime and leave the window open to run a 2nd task that has a variable input.

> start cmd /k c:\users\test\desktop\dmiwtool1.1\win64\dmiwtoolx64.exe & cd c:\users\test\desktop\dmiwtool1.1\win64\

If I run either by itself, they work (runs the exe, ends at /desktop prompt), but in this sequence only the first runs.

Answer (score 0):

this works here:

```
@ECHO OFF
START /b "" "path\program.exe" "parameter"
CD %UserProfile%\Desktop
```

Do not use `setlocal` in your Batch or put `endlocal` in the line before the `CD` command.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
start cmd /k "c:\users\test\desktop\dmiwtool1.1\win64\dmiwtoolx64.exe & cd c:\users\test\desktop\dmiwtool1.1\win64\"
```

If you leave out the quote marks, the `start` command and the `cd` command are run separately.